# php two dimensional array with sums to table

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

im in serach for a generic piece of code that uses and array

```
$arr[$key1][$key2] = $value;
```

output should be like this where "SUM" is not part of the array.

```
&nbsp;    | 1st key2 | 2nd key2 | 3rd key2 | SUM
1st key1  |       10 |       10 |       10 |  30
2nd key1  |       10 |       10 |       10 |  30
3rd key1  |       10 |       10 |       10 |  30
SUM       |       30 |       30 |       30 |  90
```

so i startet an output to see how far i get:

```
echo '<table width="100%"><thead>';
foreach($arr as $linekey => $line)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th align="center">';
    echo '</th>';
    foreach($line as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<th align="center">';
        echo $key;
        echo '</th>';
    }
    echo '<th align="center">';
    echo 'SUM';   //adding the SUM column
    echo '</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    break;
}
echo '</thead><tbody>';
foreach($arr as $key1 => $value1)
{ echo '<tr>';
     echo'<td>'.$key1.'</td>';
     $sumRow = 0; //reset sumRow
    foreach($arr[$key1] as $key2 => $value2)
    {
         echo'<td>'.round($arr[$key1][$key2],0).'</td>';      
         $sumRow += $arr[$key1][$key2]; //summing up rows
         $sumAll += $arr[$key1][$key2]; //summing up everything
         $sumCol += $arr[$key1][$key2]; //where should be this?
    }
    echo'<td>'.round($sumRow,0).'</td>'; //echo $sumRow
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

this alaredy works but im not sure where to sum the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array `$sumCol` to gather columns sums:

```
$sumCol[$key2] += $arr[$key1][$key2];
```

It size should be as number of columns.

You cannot do it in one loop without an array because you loop over columns index internally, so you could gather only `sumRow` in one temporary variable (without array).

Then, at the end:

```
echo '<tr><td>SUM</td>';
    foreach($sumCol as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        echo'<td>'.round($sumCol[$key2],0).'</td>'; //echo $sumCol
    }
echo '</tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

The other way is to define the second loop where you iterate first over columns and at second, internally, over rows.

Comment: this code works (you just want to echo the value not the eky i guess?) but i just encountered another problem what if the first key doenst have all the possible 2nd keys? then my table wont build up correctly.